# What song is used in these videos? There are two examples:

Tags: instrumental

What song is used in these videos? There are two examples:

https://youtu.be/0m63LNVHP1U

https://youtu.be/Vt5TYS3tGE8

Comment: Jincheng Zhang uses freely available music from the YouTube Audio Library which is not usually identifiable.

Answer (score 2):

[Cha Cappella by Jimmy Fontanez/Media Right Productions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8oLk0jyaxk)